# Port is not available

Tags: arduino-galileo

I'm trying to connect my **Arduino Galileo** to Linux via Arduino IDE. Sometimes I'm able to do so, but other times I ge the following error `'Board at /dev/ttyACM0 is not available'`. With **dmesg** I can see that the device is not recognized, a deeper look at this issue led me to find out that a ls on `/dev/ttyACM0` shows this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      296 Apr  8 20:14 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Here I notice that there's a missing 'c' before the permissions that is common to every other `/dev/tty*`. I would like to know the reason why and if this is the cause for my problem. This seems to be suspicious..or maybe I'm mistaken...please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If "c" is missing then it's a regular file. Probably something tried to open it with the `O_CREAT` flag without the device being there, and that created the file. You may get some clue as to what it was if you cat the file.

Comment: @Majenko is there a way to 'revert' it?!

Comment: Delete the file, then plug the board in.

Comment: Well...it worked! Not sure why, but this /dev/ttyACMO always end up to be a regular file, and I have no clue of what is responsible for it